# Get the current company without ids or uid in Odoo / OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I need to create a function that takes a default value, this value is distinct for each company.

Thing is that I can't use the `uid` because the user can do this in any company, and I have no object to ask `ids` for because its for a default field.

Is there any way to get the current company without using `ids` or the `uid` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely understand your question.

A user may be able to do something in any company depending on their list of allowed companies, but a user can only ever do something in one company at a time.

Any user can change their current company to one of the companies they are allowed but when they do this, the company_id on the user record is changed so if you browse res.users using the UID you will always get the current company of the user.

The only exception I can think of is if you give the user a list of companies they are allowed to see and give them a button or check box to do something on that company.  In this case, your screen will need to be backed by a model and you can check on there so see which company they chose, either by browsing to see which record has the checkbox set, or if you put a button or action on a tree view, the method will get the IDs of the records selected.

Comment: Well, think this: User "U" has access to 2 companies "A" and "B", the company_id of that user is the one that belongs to the company "B", now, the user goes to create a voucher and this voucher has a default value that is different for each company. If i use the UID, when i create the voucher it brings the default value of "B" even if im in company "A" because it takes the company_id of the user. I dont have button or checkbok to take active_ids so i cant bring them from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that thourgh this code :

```
self.env['res.company']._company_default_get('your.module')
```